# Width of an inline element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How do know width of an inline element, without adding to document?

With adding

```
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.innerHTML = 'Hello, world!';
span.offsetWidth; //0
document.body.appendChild(span);
span.offsetWidth; //70
```

How without adding to document?

Sorry for my english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of an element does obviously depend on the styles used (e.g. on the font size), so it is impossible to compute the width of the element without knowing where it is in the DOM.

You may add it to some invisible element if you don't want it to show on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get a width of an element if the element itself is not part of the DOM.

You need to append it, but you may also position it outside the visible area (with position: absolute and a negative left/top property) and remove it once you got the width

Answer (score 0):

Until the element is added, there's no way to know for sure how wide it is, because it depends on the styling context.

jQuery's `width()` method has a trick that it uses for `display: none` elements, I don't know if it will work for an element that hasn't even been added to the DOM (it works by temporarily showing the element, getting the width, then hiding it again).